# Dynamic builder pattern

Tags: java, polymorphism, builder

The following is the basic builder pattern

```
enum AccountType {
     BASIC,PREMIUM;
}


class AccountBuilder {  
     private AccountBuilder(Builder builder) {}

     private static class PremiumAccountBuilder extends Builder {
           public PremiumAccountBuilder () {
              this.canPost = true;
           }

           public PremiumAccountBuilder image(Image image) {
               this.image = image;
           }
     }

     public static class Builder {
            protected String username;
            protected String email;
            protected AccountType type;
            protected boolean canPost = false;
            protected Image image;

            public Builder username(String username) {
                this.username = username;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder email(String email) {
                this.email = email;
                return this;
            }

            public Builder accountType(AccountType type) {
                this.type = type;
                return (this.type == AccountType.BASIC) ? 
                        this : new PremiumAccountBuilder();
            }

            public Account builder() {
                return new Account (this.name,this.email,this.type, this.canPost, this.image);
            }

     } 
}
```

so the premium account basically override the canPost and can set the image.

I am not sure if I can do something like

```
Account premium = new AccountBuilder.Builder().username("123").email("123@abc.com").type(AccountType.PREMIUM).image("abc.png").builder();
```

like after the `type` method call if it's a premium account then i can be able to make the `image` method call.

It gives me an error as it couldn't recognize and find the image method. I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it or not, or is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

`accountType` returns an object of type `Builder`, which doesn't have an `image` method.  A possible solution is to add an `image` method to the `Builder` class that just ignores the `Image`, which is then overridden by the `PremiumBuilder`'s `image` method when it can do something useful with the `Image`; an alternative is to pass an `Image` into the `accountType` method, which is then responsible for passing the `Image` to the `PremiumBuilder`'s constructor

Comment: @user1389813 In that case pass the `Image` to an overloaded `accountType` method; or include the `Image` as a field or method in the `AccountType` class so that the `accountType` method can retrieve it and pass it to the `PremiumBuilder` constructor

Comment: What did you mean by overloaded accountType method ? and in that case how do you set the image ?

Comment: @user1389813 You can have multiple `accoutType` methods, in this case `accountType(AccountType type)` and `accountType(AccountType type, Image image)`; the second method's implementation would pass `image` to the `PremiumBuilder` constructor